# Correct URL for Azure AD B2C login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've set up my app to use Azure AD B2C. The app has a public page that allows anonymous access and this is where I have a login link to Azure AD B2C login page. I'm getting the URL for this link from the following place on Azure portal under my `Sign up or Sign in policies`:
[image]

I just click the "Copy" button I circled and paste it into my link on my public page.

What's strange is that if I click the link on the public page, it takes me to Azure AD B2C login page where I login but when I get redirected back to my app, for some reason, it doesn't like it and sends me back to the login page again.

However, if I simply try to go to the protected area in my app directly i.e. `http://localhost:49065/member`, I automatically get redirected to Azure AD B2C login page and once I login, it redirects me back to my app and everything works fine.

So, it doesn't seem to like the URL I'm using in my link. Any idea where I can get the correct URL for Azure AD B2C login that I can use on my public page?

**UPDATE:**

Here are the two URLs. The first one doesn't work and the second one does. There are some differences between the two.

The first one is the one I got from the Azure Portal -- see image above. This one does NOT really work because it kicks me back to login again:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_MyApp_SignUp_SignIn&client_id=aed18b8d-cc45-a612-82b3-5128f414d22d&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49065%2Fmember&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

This one is generated by `MSAL.js`. This is the URL I get when I get redirected to the Azure AD B2C login page if I try to go directly to a protected area of my app. This one works nicely:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_myapp_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmyb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwebclient%2Fopenid%20openid%20profile&client_id=aed18b8d-cc45-a612-82b3-5128f414d22d&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49065%2Fmember&state=c3088fbf-a895-43c7-8f9b-4f0351631323&nonce=26b3cb5c-7cc5-40c9-935f-654735d4c9b1&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS&x-client-Ver=0.1.5&client-request-id=3b769d57-3c6d-45bb-bd83-f126ab525218&prompt=select_account&response_mode=fragment
```

Any idea why the one I get from the portal doesn't work or why the second one does?

Comment: The "run now" endpoint URL is used for testing an Azure AD B2C policy. Is this an ASP.NET app?

Comment: That’s the same URL I get when I copy it by clicking the copy button.

Comment: Just posted an update with the URLs. The one I get from the Azure portal doesn't work. The second one is the one generated by `MSAL.js` and it works nicely. Any idea why?

Comment: The key difference is MSAL.js generates a `nonce` value before it sends the auth request to Azure AD B2C and then validates the `nonce` value after it receives the auth response from Azure AD B2C. If it is valid, then the auth response is accepted. If it is missing or it is invalid, then the auth response is rejected. The `nonce` value mitigates against a replay attack.

Comment: I need to put a link on my public page to Azure login and looks like MSAL doesn’t like it if the response doesn’t have a nonce value in it. What’s the right approach here? From the public page, I can link to a protected area’s URL and let MSAL take care of redirecting but that’s a kludge.

Comment: The correct URL for Azure AD B2C login should be the last one. The ednpoint for the Sign-up or sign-in policy cannot match the flow of authentication/authorization. For example, when call back to your app, the request doesn't contain the neccessary information,like sate,code and id_token in the body . It only puts the id_token in the request. This is becuase they have  different Referer.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Where do I get that URL from? I need to copy and paste that URL to use in a hyperlink on a static page that will send the user to login screen on Azure AD B2C.

Comment: @Sam The public page should redirect to a protected page, which hosts MSAL.js, that initiates the login request. Yes, it is a kludge, but MSAL.js must initiate the login request with the nonce value.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Thanks Chris! Would you mind posting this as an answer so that I can accept it. I'd like you to get credit for your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Run now"-generated authentication request is used for testing an Azure AD B2C policy.

The key difference between an MSAL.js-generated authentication request and the "Run now" one is MSAL.js generates a nonce value before it sends the authentication request to Azure AD B2C and then validates the nonce value after it receives the authentication response from Azure AD B2C. If it is valid, then the authentication response is accepted. If it is missing or it is invalid, then the authentication response is rejected. The nonce value mitigates against a replay attack.

This means the login link must initiate the authentication request by either invoking MSAL.js or redirecting to a protected page that invokes it.

Comment: A follow up question: is it possible to invoke the authentication process in `MSAL.js` from a static HTML page? My public facing page is a static HTML page. If my login button on the static page points to a protected area of my SPA app, I get an ugly login process i.e. my `React` component is half rendered before getting redirected to Azure AD B2C login page. Just ugly! The other option is to turn my static HTML page into a `React` component and allow anonymous access but the page is professionally designed and heavily uses `jQuery`. Easiest option would be to invoke `MSAL.js` from HTML page.

Comment: The plan is to get a new public page design and implement it as a React component so that the app is truly a SPA. In the interim though, I think both the easiest and cleanest approach would be to invoke MSAL.js from HTML page.